# watson concept insight api - how to get vector representation of concept?

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using [watson concept insight api](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/concept-insights-v2). I am successful at receiving the concepts however I'd also like to get their vector representation so I could measure the distance between different concepts. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has a method to measure the [distance between concepts](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/concept-insights/api/v2/#get_relation_scores_concept) but it doesn't provide the vector representation of a concept. See the 
[API specification](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/concept-insights-v2).